# how do I combine some elements into one element of a row matrix

Tags: matlab

I need to combine some elements into one element of a row matrix in MATLAB. For example, my matrix is
`[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`. I want to transform the matrix like `[1234 5678]`. Please help me do this.

Comment: Can this case occur and what would you like the output to be? `[1:12;13:24]` And how about the other assumptions that people made?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following anonymous function for a generalized numeric solution for combining single digits:

```
combineDigits = @(x) x*(10.^(length(x)-1:-1:0)).';
```

Each element of `x` must be on `[0,9]` (i.e. single digits). For your example input:

```
>> x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
x =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
>> x1 = x(1:4); x2 = x(5:end);
>> combineDigits(x1)
ans =
        1234
>> combineDigits(x2)
ans =
        5678
>>
```

The anonymous function `combinedDigits` can be applied with any general utility function, such as `cellfun`, to process blocks of data.  For example, consider the `2x8` matrix `M` of digits, partitioned into a `2x2` cell array of `1x4` digit arrays:

```
>> M = randi(9,2,8)
M =
     4     8     6     8     7     7     6     7
     9     9     1     9     7     4     2     1
>> Mpartitioned = mat2cell(M,[1 1],[4 4]) % specify ANY valid partitioning here
Mpartitioned = 
    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
>> Mcompacted = cellfun(combineDigits,Mpartitioned)
ans =
        4868        7767
        9919        7421
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
vec1=a(1:4)  %put a suitable number here
vec1=num2str(vec1);
vec1(ismember(vec1,' ')) = [];
vec1=str2double(vec1);
```

Similarly, perform the above sequence of operation on the latter half of the vector and simply concatenate them in the final vector.

Note: This solution works only for a row vector as you mentioned in the question (you mentioned row matrix, but I assume this is what you meant).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you can guarantee that your row will always be a multiple of 4, you could do the following:

```
reshape(sum(bsxfun(@times,reshape(Q',4,[])',[1000,100,10,1]),2),[],size(Q,1))';
```

What this does is `reshape` the matrix like so:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     ->    [1 2 3 4
 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]           5 6 7 8
                            8 7 6 5
                            4 3 2 1]
```

We then multiple each row by `[1000,100,10,1]` and sum each row:

```
[1 2 3 4          [1000 200 30 4         [1234
 5 6 7 8    ->     5000 600 70 8   ->     5678
 8 7 6 5           8000 700 60 5          8765
 4 3 2 1]          4000 300 20 1]         4321]
```

Finally we reshape the matrix again to get back to the original shape.

```
[1234         [1234 5678
 5678   ->     8765 4321]
 8765          
 4321]
```

Comment: here comes one liner! :)

Comment: Quite a long one though. Fixed a small bug in the outer reshape call and slightly simplfied the inner one.

Comment: Cheers, I have to admit I wasn't aware of the empty bracket simplification. I have learnt something new today.

Answer (score 1):

First define your values in a numeric array:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
```

Next convert to a string:

```
b = num2str(a);
```

Now remove all the spaces:

```
b(find(b == ' ')) = '';
```

Insert an empty space in the middle and then convert back to a numeric array (I think this is what you want(?)):

```
c = str2num([b(1:4),' ',b(5:end)]);
```

So that

```
>> c(1)

ans =

        1234

>> c(2)

ans =

        5678
```

Edit:  Added 'end' to cover an arbitrary range.

Comment: Note that this will give unexpected results if the numbers are greater than 9.

Comment: Yes your right so I added 'end' to cover an arbitrary range. It still isn't that clear to me how to generalize the "split" point, just with the information we have. Thanks.